# I'm wondering what mechanisms other than senderID are available to help stop spoofing a from: address from your domain

Tags: email, smtp

This might be an interesting question of sorts... I'm wondering what mechanisms other than senderID are available to help stop or flag someone from spoofing a from: address from your domain when sending spam to someone else in your domain. For Example: sending a message that is From: admin@yourdomain To: someone@yourdomain.

I ask because it doesn't seem to be much of a problem, and yet spammers would surely use this technique as it would be quite effective. So I'm guessing mail servers or firewalls must be filtering this this kind of spoofed message.

After all your inbound mail servers's SMTP port 25 must be open to accept reception of unauthenticated messages destined to one of your your domain's users. Right?

I ask because I've recently learned that our web site team is sending administrative type e-mail to users inside our domain and they just made up a fictitious e-mail address for the From: field, and yet the message are getting through???

Given that, why aren't our users getting absolutely bombed with spam like this?

That last statement kind of reminds me of the Fermi paradox, "If aliens should exists where are they?"

:)

Comment: Your website team is likely sending from IP addresses that are authorized via your SenderID/SPF record. An outside spammer would not be. That's the entire point of the system, so I'm not sure why you're asking "what mechanisms *other* than senderID are available." It's like asking "other than food, what can people eat?"

Comment: Thanks, but the site is on azure and they are using a sendgrid account, our spf records only authorize our own SMTP server public IP.

Comment: Then these messages would be failing SPF checks. Whether or not to reject them at that point is up to you and your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Dead simple: Just drop everything that comes from the outside unauthenticated and claims to come from your domain.  Of course that only works if you can decide that all clients must either send from inside your network or send mail via authenticated channels.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's more or less how I figured the mail server must be dealing with this kind of message, But if that was the case then how are the web site's administrative emails getting through? But because they are getting through, it left me wondering why we aren't getting buried with this kind of spam...